# Symfony2 - Form errors (for the entire form, NOT individual fields) not displaying

Tags: php, forms, symfony, error-handling

Cross-posted from the Symfony2 Google Group since there haven't been any responses to my question.

I have the following form:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="{{ path('_contact') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Send us a message</legend>

        {{ form_errors(form) }}

        <div>
            <p class="label">{{ form_label(form.name) }}</p>
            {{ form_widget(form.name, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'input' } }) }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="label">{{ form_label(form.email) }}</p>
            {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'input' } }) }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="label">{{ form_label(form.subject) }}</p>
            {{ form_widget(form.subject, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'input' } }) }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="label">{{ form_label(form.message) }}</p>
            {{ form_widget(form.message, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'input', 'rows' : '8', 'placeholder' : 'Type your message here' } }) }}
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
            <p class="label">{{ form_label(form.honeypot) }}</p>
            {{ form_widget(form.honeypot) }}
        </div>

        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </fieldset>
```

I don't like having field errors appear directly near their fields.  I want to just have a list of all the errors above the form itself, which is why I don't have an error for each field.  I'm using a slightly modified form_errors theme:

```
{# src/MajorProductions/SewingDiva/SiteBundle/Resources/views/errors.html.twig #}
{% block form_errors %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if errors|length > 0 %}
            <div class="errors">
                <ul>
                    {% for error in errors %}
                        <li>{{
                        error.messagePluralization is null
                        ? error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators')
                        : error.messageTemplate|transchoice(error.messagePluralization, error.messageParameters, 'validators')
                        }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

I just put the default setup in a `<div>` so I can style it a bit easier.

My problem is that a list of form errors isn't displaying at all.  As in, no empty `<div>` in the HTML, no nothing.  If I put in the code for a field-level error, like say {{ form_errors(form.email) }}, it displays.

I guess I could kludge it with something like:

```
<div class="errors">
    {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

But that doesn't really address the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try the following theme, it works for me :

```
{% block form_errors %}
    {% spaceless %}
         {% if errors|length > 0 %}
              {% if compound %}
              <ul class="form-errors">
                  {% for error in errors %}
                  <li>{{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators') }}</li>
                  {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% else %}
              <ul class="form-field-errors">
                  {% for error in errors %}
                  <li>{{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators') }}</li>
                  {% endfor %}
             </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

Note the use of the ***compound*** option.

You might have to set error_bubbling to true for each field

(Nb : This is not from me, i don't remember the kind guy who should be credited for this)